# How do i parse this name class to winform button function c#

Tags: c#

```
class FullNameClass
{
    public string xFullName { get; set; }
    public string lcFirstName { get; set; }
    public string lcMiddleName { get; set; }
    public string lcLastname { get; set; }
    public string lcSuffix { get; set; }

    public string getfirstanme(string xFullName)
    {

        string[] words = xFullName.ToUpper().Split(' ');
        int numberOfWords = words.Length;

        if (numberOfWords == 3)
        {
            if (numberOfWords == 3)
            {
                string[] fullname = xFullName.Split(new Char[] { ' ' });
                if (fullname[1].Length > 2)
                {
                    string firstname = fullname[0] + " " + fullname[1];
                    lcFirstName = firstname;
                    lcMiddleName = null;
                    lcLastname = null;
                    lcSuffix = null;
                    return lcFirstName;

                }
```

itry to use this code but it shows blank
in Form under button functions

```
FullNameClass fullname = new FullNameClass();
fullname.xFullName = "Robert A Smith";
Messagebox.show(fullname.lcFirstName);
```

Hope someone will help me on this
by the way im newbie in coding and also learn from reading only
please be patient about my code

Comment: Please post compilable code. Right now your class is cut off halfway through.

Comment: In order for the code inside the method to run, you need to call it, you're bypassing it by just setting the `xFullName` property, you also need to call the method.

Comment: Also understand that picking apart a single string with the name of a person into *correct* first, last, middle names, is considered a hard problem, because there are so many rules and exceptions. See https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/15326/how-to-deal-with-particles-in-a-last-name-in-a-reference-list for some examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the method in you case:

```
MessageBox.Show(fullname.getfirstanme(fullname.xFullName));
```

But, there is a lot to be improved here.

---

Besides the obvious typo's, the FullName class should be redesigned.

For starters, all these properties:

```
public string xFullName { get; set; }
public string lcFirstName { get; set; }
public string lcMiddleName { get; set; }
public string lcLastname { get; set; }
public string lcSuffix { get; set; }
```

are both `set` and `get`.

There is nothing fancy about them: if you dont set them, you wont get a result.

A common way to approach this problem is to think about how you want your object to behave.

Let me give you an example. Let's say, you know upfront you'll always use the fullname as input. Then you can apply this to a constructor:

```
class FullNameClass
{
    public string lcFirstName { get; } //read only
    public FullNameClass(string fullName) // required to initialize the class
    {
        // set the firstname property with your logic
        lcFirstName  = getfirstanme(fullName);

        //you can apply this pattern for the other properties as well
    }
}
```

Comment: ill try this code i'll let you know if its work by the way its fullname parser should i do this on MI LastName and Suffix?

Comment: See my update: I would say: make the properties readonly and extract them from your routine - fill it during object initialization.